# Slideshow overlaps footer

Tags: jquery, css, css-position

I'm working on a responsive page, and tried everything (including the search function here) but the footer keeps sliding under the  content/slideshow. What am I doing wrong?

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="content">

    <div class="slideshow"> 
        <img src="img/1.JPG" width="850" />
        <img src="img/2.JPG" width="850" />
        <img src="img/3.JPG" width="850" />
    </div> <!-- Ends Slideshow -->

</div> <!-- Ends Content -->

<div id="footer">   
</div>
</div>

Style-sheet:

#wrapper { width: 900px; margin: 0 auto 0 auto; }
#content { padding: 20px 30px 0 30px; height: auto; }
.slideshow { position:relative; height:auto; max-width: 100%; margin-bottom: 10px; }
.slideshow img { max-width:100%; height: auto; }
#footer { padding: 20px 0 0 0; }
```

Comment: I don't see it overlapping with that code.  See: http://jsfiddle.net/0qe47o5e/

Comment: Thanks, I updated your Jsfiddle to match my current code: http://jsfiddle.net/0qe47o5e/1/

Comment: Resolved.  see my answer (It's updated).  Have a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to make absolute element take space on a page, because they don't do that by definition.  However you can give a height to the `#content` to fix.

Since you know the height of your images (according to your jsfiddle in the comments), so you can add `height:450px;` to your `#content` because `height:auto` will not see any height on your `absolute` positioned elements.

`#content { padding: 20px 30px 0 30px; height:450px;}`

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0qe47o5e/3/

OR Code Snippet

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#wrapper { width: 900px; margin: 0 auto 0 auto; }
#content { padding: 20px 30px 0 30px; height: 450px; }
.slideshow { position:relative; height:100%; max-width: 100%; margin-bottom: 10px; }
.slideshow img { max-width:100%; }
#footer { padding: 20px 0 0 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="content">

    <div class="slideshow"> 
        <img src="img/1.JPG" width="850" height="450" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: block; z-index: 3; opacity: 1;" />
        <img src="img/2.JPG" width="850" height="450" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none; z-index: 2; opacity: 0;" />
        <img src="img/3.JPG" width="850" height="450" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none; z-index: 1; opacity: 0;" />
    </div> <!-- Ends Slideshow -->

</div> <!-- Ends Content -->

<div id="footer">   Footer HERE
</div>
</div>
```